# how to hide unsupported interface methods from class

Tags: java, interface

I have a interface:

```java
public interface Service {
    default Type service1(Type t) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    default Type service2(Type t) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

and a class implementing this interface but only needs service2:

```java
class MyService implements Service{
    @Override
    Type service2(Type t) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I create a myservice-instance:

```java
Service s = new MyService();
s.service1(t); // throws error at runtime
```

Is there a better way to hide or mark that service1() method to signal that nobody should use this unsupported method in code (for example, by annotation?). Or do I have to create another pattern for such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Service` interface (from your description of it) is a clear violation of the interface-segregation principle ([ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)). You should have two interfaces for `Service1` and `Service2`. If you need an aggregation, you can get it through an interface called `AggregatedService` which will extend `Service1` and `Service2`.

With your current design, it is not possible to hide one method only from the external system.

Comment: In your system, there are entities which depend only on `Service1` and some which depend only on `Service2`. That said, I am assuming there are classes which depend on both `Service1` and `Service2`. The OO approach here will be to expose only the interface that the class actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Deprecated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation. This tells other developers that this method is no longer supported, and planned to be removed in future versions. Your new interface might look like this:

```java
public interface Service {

    @Deprecated
    default Type service1(Type t) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    default Type service2(Type t) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Not only will it come up with a warning for people using it during compile-time, it will also highlight, telling people they are using deprecated Api's in most modern IDE's.

Comment: No, cannot use this, because there are other "Service-Objects", such as "UserService" implementing Service-Interface and this "UserService" can supports service1()-method.

Comment: So it is only not supported for specific classes?

Comment: yes. There are Service-classes supporting one method but not the other..

Comment: In that case, I recommend @farhanjk's answer.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation inherits all methods from its implemented interface. So if you create an instance of this implementation, you can access all (non private) methods in this implementation and implemented interface.